# I'm looking at a 1978 F-150 Truck that pulls to the left in between Shifting gears. Where ould be a good place to start looking?

Tags: ford, steering, f-150

This truck pulls when you let off the accelerator in between shifting gears

Comment: Brakes sticking on that side? What about general steering linkage maintenance and an alignment?

Comment: Is the truck 4-wheel drive?

Comment: Exactly when between shifting gears, during the disengage, or re-engage of the clutch/tranny?

Comment: No brakes aren't sticky and yes it is a 4X4. It happens on deceleration between shifts, has nothing to do with trans

Answer (score 1):

My belief is you've got worn rear axle mounts / rear suspension mounts. Elevate rear frame onto solid jackstands.  Grab axle and shake it hard.  Grab tire and shake it hard. I'm guessing something is loose (and possibly unsafe). Replace worn out components / shackles.

Comment: Worn rear axle mounts? So leaf spring bushings? I'm going to check the U bolts as well when I get it.